# Does a Bear Archery bow quiver influence my Grizzly?

Tags: gear, archery, recurve-bow

I've a Bear Archery Grizzly recurve bow. Bows from this manufacturer are commonly equipped with two threads to attach a Bear Archery bow quiver. You can see them in this image:

[image]

If I attach an original Bear Archery bow quiver to my Grizzly, does this anyhow influence my bow?

[image]

Comment: Well, for sure it will make your bow heavier and clunkier, thus making it harder/more exhausting to aim and shoot...

Comment: Also, from a physicists point of view, you are attaching a weight that is not symmetric with respect to the bow's vertical symmetry axis. This will shift the center of gravity sideways, and will give the bow a tendency to tip to one side. Hence, you will not only have to compensate for the extra weight but also for this torque trying to tip your bow sideways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earlier answers were "Technically" correct, but how many bows are in use today with a quiver attached?  Again, strictly scientifically speaking, yes it adds weight to one side, however in real world use it will not likely affect your bow in any negative way.  Millions of people shoot bows with quivers attached every day.  I think you can adjust to it just fine with practice/time.

If you hunt I'd use the bow quiver, if you just target shoot maybe forego the bow quiver and use a hip/back/side quiver.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a quiver to the bow will increase the amount of noise, and also increase the amount of interference of the flight of the arrow as it leaves the bow. It also makes your bow heavier increasing the amount of effort to aim and hold the aim.